# Conventions for touchscreen directional controller input?

Tags: input, touch-screen, games

I want a simple joystick-like input widget for touch devices (phones and tablets) that is effectively 5 buttons: left, right, up, down, and stop. It's the main control of a game and it let's the player direct an object around the screen. Something like this:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXEUoV.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

So what I'm looking for are established conventions for this kind of control on a touch screen, if there are any.

Comment: Don't have balsamiq mockups :(. Would like to request to upload a pdf file?

Comment: @Andy - the Balsamiq mockup is displayed as a PNG file on this page, don't know why you can't see it.

Answer (score 1):

The [**Android developer portal**](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/227) has a couple of widgets - since it is on the dev portal, it's quite understandable that it must be in use. https://android-arsenal.com/tag/227

This youtube video is showing a practical use of it. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NdWZq8vdKhs